# How to save data in a Java program

Tags: java

Is there a way to make a collection of class files/objects and then have them used in an interactive main file? So let's say I want to make a program to store information interactively where different classes are designed to hold different information. Then I would have an interactive main file where I made instances of these classes which would collectively hold the information I want stored. And then any changes or anything I do in this interactive main file is then saved.

I understand that this might be a very odd inquiry and maybe some other program might be useful for this.  If so, feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "Interactive"

Can you give us an example of how this code would operate?

Possibly giving us a real world example (or a made up one) ?

Comment: How i would want it to work would be something like this. I make a class "person" which holds information like name, phone number etc. I would then like to make a home-made registry which would be interactive. So lets say im introduced to Peter and would want to store him. i would the. Make an instance (Person person1 = new Person("Peter", 123456789). After this if i ever access this program again the instance involving peter will still be accessible and i can change/add information in accordance to any methods i have in the person class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions that are good for the purpose you mentioned in your comment.

The first one is called [Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm). This let's you save your java object to your hard drive, and retrieve it later.

The second, (and in this case, more preferable option in my opinion), is using a Database.

A database is a compliment to your program, that stores data. You can then use "Queries" to access this data, and update it. Almost every database software is compatible with java.

I would look into [MySQL](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/)

The reason I think a database would be better for your purpose is that they are already highly optimized, and are designed to have multiple people accessing and writing to them at once. If you wanted just want one person to use this program at a time however, serialization might be easier to implement.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: If this turns out to be a good solution for you, I would appreciate if you would mark it as your selected answer :)

(Feel free to wait and try out both of those technologies, and wait for other answers, before you choose)

Comment: A bit new to the site, all marked now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Your main class would use the standard input (perhaps `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`) and output (`System.out.println()`). To interact with your other classes, most simply, just put them in the same folder (if you are interested take a look at [Java *packages*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)). If you have a Dog class in the same folder as your main class, you can freely create Dog objects in your main class. I hope this helps!

As a side note, because you mentioned storing information with different classes, you might be interested in the [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html).

Comment: I guess this would work but maybe not in the way i intended. See my response to the other comment. Ideally i would also make this main file able to be used by different people. As if me and 5 other people would like to collectively make a register using the Person class for example.

Comment: This is what I initially thought he was asking, but now it looks like this is a question about serializing objects

Comment: It seems I can't comment on your post for lack of reputation. Are you opposed to writing data out to a file and reading it back in later?